# Why can I access DynamoDB, but not SSM?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-ssm

I'm currently developing a node application running on AWS infrastructre which accesses DynamoDB and SSM.

I'm not proficient enough with Node to create a MVCE, but those are the pieces that seem relevant to me:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
AWS.config.update({ region: 'eu-west-1' })
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
const ssm = new AWS.SSM()

const ssmQueryParams = {
  Name: '/foo/bar/tablename',
  WithDecryption: true
}

let ssmQueryResult
ssmQueryResult = (await ssm.getParameter(ssmQueryParams).promise())

const tableName = ssmQueryResult.Parameter.Value

const ddbParams = {
  TableName: tableName,
  Key: {
    'foo_id': fooId
  }
}
const ddbQueryResult = (await ddb.get(ddbParams).promise())
```

So I want to get the DynamoDB table name from SSM. If I remove the SSM part, the code works. But with it, I get

```
{ Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 169.123.123.123:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1097:14)
  message: 'Missing credentials in config',
  errno: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
  code: 'CredentialsError',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '169.123.123.123',
  port: 80,
  time: 2019-06-25T12:34:02.909Z,
  originalError:
   { message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers',
     errno: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
     code: 'CredentialsError',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: '169.123.123.123',
     port: 80,
     time: 2019-06-25T12:34:02.909Z,
     originalError:
      { errno: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
        code: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
        syscall: 'connect',
        address: '169.123.123.123',
        port: 80,
        message: 'connect EHOSTUNREACH 169.123.123.123:80' } } }
```

So why can I access the data on DynamoDB, but when I want to read from SSM, I get a credentials error?

edit: Adding `accessKeyId` and `secretAccessKey`  to `AWS.config.update` is not an option.

Comment: Are you running in EC2/VPC and using IAM roles for credentials? Is 169.123.123.123 literally the host IP in that error response, or did you modify it from 169.254.169.254?

Comment: I've edited the IP, because I thought it might be something specific to what I run - TIL, it's not: https://serverfault.com/a/427022/113899

Comment: This might be relevant: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2534

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to supply the ARN

```
arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSSMReadOnlyAccess
```

while I gave

```
arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBReadOnlyAccess
```